# How does Angular implement routing internally?

Tags: angular, browser

In my naive understanding of a web browser, I always thought that if the user enters a new URL into the browser, it would navigate away from the current page, fetch a new page from the network and then display the new page in place of the old page.

However, routing in Angular seems to disprove that naive theory.  If the browser is displaying an Angular page, and the user enter a new URL into the browser, if that URL is controlled by the routing for the Angular application, Angular simply applies its routing, the browser does not access the network, and the page is not replaced.

How does Angular circumvent the normal functioning of the browser in this way?

Comment: Angular doesn't control the flow if you type the url directly in the Url bar, If I change the url then hit enter it's the browser who will take control of what to do ... but If I click on some link in the Angular app then Angular intercepts that click and changes the View and the Url without making any call to the server (to fetch the document).

Comment: Maybe you are looking to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History (so it is clear that "Angular circumvent the normal functioning of the browser" is not the case as updating url without navigation *is* normal functioning of the browser)

Comment: @RachidO, Are you sure that is the case?  I think it will just switch to the route without fetching anything from the server

Comment: @JoelFan Yes I'm sure, If you change the Url then hit enter it's the browser who will decide what to do not Angular. But if you click on some link in the App then it's Angular who will do it's magic with the History API

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I'm not talking about clicking on a link... I'm talking about typing the URL of the route into the browser and hitting Enter

Comment: @RachidO, but then I would expect the web server to try to locate that new route's URL and come back with a 404

Comment: @JoelFan Oh ok I see, assume you typed, domain.com/a/b then the server (with some config) will return the index.html to the browser which will start the bootstraping phase of the angular app and THEN angular constructs its View Tree (and other stuff) and parses the URL and finds the View that corresponds to that Url

Comment: @RachidO.... exactly.... I was missing the server config part.... that makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways it works in different situations:

## 1st access to the application

When you do the first access to an Angular based application (either the root roite or some sub route), the browser will query the webserver about that url. Either root or some sub route responds with the same index.html that loads angular and then Angular Router get the current url and decides what to display.

**Note:** this approach is different when using [Server-side Rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

## 2nd link to some route inside the application

When using `routerLink` directive or directly triggering a route change within `Router`, the angular just replaces the URL using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History). No additional request is made (or is, depending if your application uses [Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

## 3rd changing url manually after the application have been loaded initially

Since on the first access the cache was primed, the browser will just use the cached index.html that loads the cached angular JavaScript z and this will be very fast, seeming that the page wasn't reloaded, but it was.

Comment: I don't understand how #3 would work.... The web server would try to fetch a different path and would not find index.html any more.... I would expect to get a 404 error

Comment: Htaccess url rewrite

Comment: No, a server configuration